# groovy date-format error within Jenkins CI

Tags: groovy, jenkins

we're just migrate our CI-platform (jenkins v1.538) from WinSrv2003 to WinSrv2008 via copy and paste all the job- and config files from the old server to the new on. Afterwards all jobs are running fine, except for an groovy job. Here we got an date-format error. The language and regional settings are correct (identical regional and date-settings on both servers). We also try to force the correct format within the code, but jenkins still throws the following error:

```
FATAL: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:599)
```

groovy Code:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.FilePath
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
...
def tsformat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
def to_ts_format = new SimpleDateFormat(tsformat)
def from_integrity_format = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")

.....
try {
...
  xml.changereport (job:srcjobname, time:today.format (tsformat), predecessortime:predectime.format (tsformat)) {

for (def b in builds) {       
  b_no = b.getNumber ()
  if (b_no < from || b_no > to) {
    println ("Skipped build: " + b_no)
    continue
  } else {
    println ("Processing build: " + b_no)
  }

  buildinfo (number:b.number, time:b.getTime ().format (tsformat)) {
    for (cs in b.changeSet) {
      for (ci in cs) {
        citime =  from_integrity_format.parse (ci.date)
        if (citime > predectime) {
        ...
```

At the if-condition the error will thrown.

Java-version (1.7.0), jenkins, groovy plugin etc are running with the same version as on the old server. Jobs and the groovy-scrip where not change. Is there something we forgot to configure on jenkins or server side?

Thanks Steffen

Comment: Which if statement?  There are two in that code

Answer (score 0):

This is could be happening on the line:
`buildinfo (number:b.number, time:b.getTime ().format (tsformat))` 
b.getTime() returns a DateTime object, which you're trying to format as a String (`tsFormat`)

The other place where this could be happening is:
 `citime =  from_integrity_format.parse (ci.date)`
Make sure that `parse()` expects the type of what `ci.date` is, it might be expecting a string, and you're giving it a `Date`